# Passed property to child component is being logged false per default

Tags: reactjs

I didn't know how to specify the title.

Here is my problem:

I have a parent component which passes down it's default state as properties to some child component.

One of these default states is being passed as following:

```
<FriendButton is_friend={this.props.is_friend} />
```

**FriendButton is in a child component of the parent, thats why it is this.props here**

So this is what I am trying to pass to `<FriendButton />` :

```
this.props.is_friend == true
```

So now inside my `<FriendButton />` component I want to deal with that value. Weirdly enough it gets logged as "`false`".

Here is my simple code to check that:

```
import React from 'react';

class FriendButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      friend_status: ""
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(e){
    console.log("Friend status at friend button: ",this.props);
    if(this.props.is_friend){
      this.setState({
        friend_status: "Friend"
      });
    }else{
      this.setState({
        friend_status: "Friend request"
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <button className="friend-request-button">{this.state.friend_status == "Friend" ? <i className="fa fa-check"></i> : <i className="fa fa-user-plus"></i>}{this.state.friend_status}</button>
    );
  }
}

export default FriendButton;
```

Now as you can see I am logging the `props` in the `componentWillMount()` and the logg that I receive is : `Friend status at friend button:  Object {is_friend: false}`

When I inspect my component in GoogleChrome React Tools I can clearly see that this property is set to `true` as you can see in the following image.

[image]

This has never happened to me before - any ideas what I might be missing here?

Comment: See docs for componentWillMount(): https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html more specifically 'Invoked once [...] immediately before the initial rendering occurs', leading me to think that your component at the time of the console.log has yet to receive the actual props from the parent component. Instead you should be able to pass props to your constructor and set state there.

Comment: I will try that. I checked componentWillReceiveProps() and there I can log the correct props value

Comment: @Thomas Ok using the cunstructor function to set state directly with this.props didn't work. props arent available for the component in its constructor. I have managed to get it to work. See my answer

Comment: you can't access this.props in the constructor since it this is not bound to the class, but should instead access props.is_friend after passing props - constructor(props) {[...]}. Glad you found a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Due to `componentWillMount()` being fired too early it wasn't able to receive the correct property value and therefore update the state correctly.

Using the `componentWillReceiveProps(props){}` lifecycle allowed me to achieve what I wanted.

Here is an example code on how I used that function:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    console.log("Props: ", props);
    if(props){
      var friend_status = "Friend";
    }else{
      var friend_status = "Friend request";
    }
    this.setState({
      is_friend: props,
      friend_status: friend_status
    });
  }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I'd recommend using a conditional ternary operator instead of `if/else`. That would shorten the above to `var friends_status === props ? 'Friend' : 'Friend request';`. It is (at least for me), much more readable and takes up much less space. Read more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator.